# Error building capybara-webkit

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, capybara-webkit

I am trying to install capybara-webkit on ubuntu 12.04, but I get this error:

```
$ gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.0.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/samir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Command 'qmake -spec linux-g++' not available

Makefile not found

Gem files will remain installed in /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dcaclab/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/gem_make.out
```

Any idea?

Comment: It seems gem doesn't find qmake. Do you have qmake installed? What if you run "which qmake" in a shell?

Comment: nothing printed when enter qmake, how would I install it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need `qmake`, which comes from QT (a dependency of capybara-webkit).

The capybara-webkit wiki has instructions for installing Qt and capybara-webkit on various systems: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with capybara-webkit. I tried all the steps mentioned in the wiki https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit , but that did not help me.

Then i looked at this issue https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/583 .

My `brew doctor` was complaining that my xcode version is old. I should update it. Also, I should take software updates for `command line tools`. Once i updated both, the capybara-webkit installation went smooth.

This issue is system specific. So just one answer might not resolve the issue. But keeping the `brew doctor` happy is usually good.